# Firebase+glide, caching strategy

Tags: android, firebase, caching, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm using *Glide* and *Firebase* for loading and cashing images. Usually, I use [Signature](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation)  with image created time then determine cache time. But in *Firebase* I can get created time only using second request `getMetadata()`. How do I make caching correctly when i change one image to another with same name in my storage? Should I use `getMetadata()` or there are other ways?

```
  Glide.with(getContext())
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(storageReference.child(item.getImageUrl()))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.category_image_not_found)
                    .signature(???)
                    .into(image);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was stuck in a similar situation for as long as I can remember! Using `getMetadata()` is slow, and causes delays. What I figured was that to keep my image up to date, there was no other option but to incorporate the Realtime Database. This can be done in one of the following ways :-

First :

Whenever the image at the particular storage location is edited, you update the `timestamp` for that image's node in your realtime database. And when you want to display the image, just download its timestamp and write a `Glide.signature(timestamp)` method similar to what you mentioned.

Second :

Just obtain the download URL of the image whenever you upload/edit it, and save the URL in the realtime database. In this way, whenever the image is updated, a different URL is saved to the same location. This guarantees that your cache does not show outdated images (changing URL of source is the advocated method to invalidate caches for Glide).

I understand that there could be overhead involved with retrieving data from the realtime database first and then downloading the image. However, that's the only way to go when using Glide + Firebase. Plus, enabling persistence and other realtime database quirks can make it seamlessly fast!